# Wearing womens clothing as a teenage boy

Tags: hadith, clothing

Assalamualakum, I am a 14 year old boy(not sure if age matters for the subject) recently I have recieved some clothing that turns out to be fabricated for women, a jacket, a shirt and undergarments (yes, I know but they look masculine) that are all comfortable and don't look necessarily femanine. I was wondering if I could wear these without the intent of imitating women of course, I also heard the hadith against doing this but I also heard that that hadith was weak and abandoned.

Please help me, alhamdulillah

Answer (score 1):

If the label on clothes saying "for women", it doesn't makes it Haram for men. The Hadith about this matter says to not to imitate as other gender and includes everything, from dressing to hair cut to makeup etc.

> The Prophet (sal Allahu alaihi wa sallam) said,
>
> > “Allah has cursed the women who imitate the men and the men who
> >     imitate the women.”
>
> [Musnad Imam Ahmad, Sunan Abu Dawud, Sunan at-Tirmidhi and it is
>   Authentic]

Commentary:

Also from the ones whom Allah has cursed are those men who imitate women. These are men who imitate women in their walk, their dress, the earrings in their ears and their jewellery and necklaces around their necks. They copy the length of their hair down their backs and their long nails, they cross dress into women’s clothing and act like them. All these traits are causes of the wrath and curse of Allah upon them.

There is a term for people like this in Shariah. Such people are called Mu-khanna-thoun as the Messenger (sal Allahu alaihi wa sallam) said about them: “Allah has cursed the Mukhannathoun from amongst the men.” [Related by Imam Bukhari in Al-Adab Al-Mufrad and Sunan At-Tirmidhi and it is an authentic Hadith]

These people are pure evil unless they repent to Allah sincerely and unless Allah accepts their repentance.

So any man, who softens their voice like a woman, sits like a woman, walks like a woman, plays on people’s attention like a woman and even uses the makeup that women use is included in this curse.

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/81994/he-likes-to-imitate-women